# mapStateToProps passes only one object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

mapStateToProps has got three objects in an array, but when passed to render it passes only one object. how to get all the objects in render map function... following is my code.

```
class AppliedCandidates extends Component {

render() {
    const {appliedjob} = this.props
    console.log('================+++++====================');
    console.log("appliedjob ", appliedjob);
    console.log('================+++++====================');
    return (
       <div>
            { appliedjob && appliedjob.map(job => {

            return (<div>
                    <h5>{job.jobid}</h5>
                    <h6>{job.candidatephoneno}</h6>
                    </div>
                )})
            }
       </div> 
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
console.log("state" , state); 
return {
    appliedjob:state.getAppliedJobs.appliedjob
}
   }
```

at render :

```
appliedjob  [{…}]
```

at mapstatetoprops

```
getAppliedJobs:
appliedjob: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
authError: ""
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have added the whole code? I don't see the connect() here. Please share code sandbox link here to help us better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You have to map all state values to props individually or you can also map the whole state object:

This should work though:

```
`const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("state" , state); 
    return {
        appliedjob:state.getAppliedJobs.appliedjob,
        getAppliedJobs: state.getAppliedJobs.getAppliedJobs,
        authError: state.getAppliedJobs.authError
   }
})`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
state.getAppliedJobs.appliedjob
```

seems like you're trying call the function from the redux store instead of just mapping the state of the store, try

```
appliedjob:state.appliedjob
```

and get Redux devtools, they really helpful with all that stuff